# What types are allowed in config.yaml in juju charms?

Tags: configuration, juju

The "config.yaml" settings inside juju charms contain a type - e.g.:

```
pip_no_index:
    default: False
    type: boolean
    description: "Prevent pip connecting to Python Package Index to download packages"
```

This type defaults to string if not provided. The only ones I've seen in existing charms are:

- string
- boolean
- int

Is it possible to have other types? Specifically, `list` or `dictionary`? Is there a list of charm config types anywhere?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All available types (as of [r2798](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~go-bot/juju-core/trunk/files/2798)):

- string (default)
- int
- float
- boolean

From [the code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~go-bot/juju-core/trunk/view/2798/charm/config.go#L54):

```go
var optionTypeCheckers = map[string]schema.Checker{
    "string":  schema.String(),
    "int":     schema.Int(),
    "float":   schema.Float(),
    "boolean": schema.Bool(),
}
```

If a `type:` setting is found in `config.yaml` which doesn't match one of these, then it throws the error:

> option [option_name] has unknown type [type]

This is a shame. I'd have very much liked the option of a `dictionary` or `map` type